# Why this raises compilation error when trying to increment the value and put it back to HashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap, hashtable

In the last line I am trying to get the value, increase it and then put it back. Questions :

1. why it raises compilation error "Invalid argument to operation ++/--"
2. In order to increment the value in this particular example, is there a better way to do so?

   ```
   Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
   map.put("hello", 4);
   // we wanna get 4 to increase it
   map.put("hello",++(map.get("hello"))); // Invalid argument to operation ++/--
   ```

Answer (score 3):

You can only do `++` on a variable (not on an arbitrary expression). Use `... + 1` instead:

```
map.put("hello", map.get("hello") + 1);
```

or, if you're using Java 8:

```
map.merge("hello", 1, (a,b) -> a + b));
```

(Note that Java does not have any feature corresponding to C++ references.)

Comment: I am not getting "(a,b) -> a + b"

Comment: The `merge` method updates the value at `key` by either using the second argument `1`, or, if there's already a mapping, the second argument `1` and the existing value `v` and applies the merge function, in this case a simple addition: `1+v`. It's the syntax for a lambda expression (an anonymous function). This feature was introduced in Java 8. (Google on java lambda if you want to know more on the subject.)

Comment: @Cgraphics, was my explanation clear? If so, please consider accepting the answer (otherwise, please let me know and I can elaborate).

Answer (score 1):

You can use Apache commons [MutableInt](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/mutable/MutableInt.html)

```
Map<String, MutableInt> map = new HashMap<String, MutableInt>();
map.put("hello", new MutableInt(4));
map.get("hello").increment();
```

Comment: Good one! But you didn't answer the first question.